# How to response a DNS request when only part of the queries is answered?

Tags: request, dns, response

Some DNS request may contain multiple queries, and my server is **NOT** `Recursion Available`, if i can only answer part of the queries, how do i respond?

To be more specify, how to set the `RCODE`?

Comment: this question is on-topic because it deals with the software level _implementation_ details of a DNS server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you receive multiple questions in the `QUESTION` section of a single query, just return `FORMERR` (`RCODE = 1`) to the entire query.

As you've found, the semantics for the `RCODE` field in these circumstances are not defined.

I did write an Internet Draft (i.e. a pre-publication RFC) that described a possible solution but the problem turned out to be too hard so I abandoned it.

Comment: Awesome!! By ```FORMERR``` you mean the former ones the server can resolve? whenever something not found, just break there?

Comment: @Topro no, `FORMERR` is an RCODE - every full DNS implementation I know of will return that RCODE if it sees a query with more than one question in it (i.e. `QDCOUNT > 1`).